# Jquery IF ELSE animation

Tags: jquery, css

Been learning Jquery and been trying to write a little bit of code that does an animation when you click a button and does the opposite when you click it again (basically moving a circle from right to left each time you click the button. Quite a simple animation, just struggling to get it to do it using an if/else statement in Jquery)

Currently I am at:

```
$(document).on('click', '#sub', function(){
var moved = 0;
if (moved == 0) {
   $('.circle').animate({'margin-left': "300px"});
   moved = 1;
}
else{
    moved = 0;
    $('.circle').animate({'margin-left': "-300px"});
}
});
```

So I am trying to move .circle right 300px, it runs the if statement part fine, its when I change moved to a a value of 1 that nothing happens. Should I maybe using a while loop or what should I maybe be doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your `moved` var more globally. Now when the click event is triggered `moved` will always be `0` because it set this way.

```
(function() {
    var moved = 0;

    $(document).on('click', '#sub', function(){
        if (moved == 0) {
           $('.circle').animate({'margin-left': "300px"});
           moved = 1;
        }
        else{
            moved = 0;
            $('.circle').animate({'margin-left': "-300px"});
        }
    });   
})();
```

Now it will "save" the state of `moved` variable outside the click event scope.

Edit, a little extra a shorter version of the code:

```
(function() {
    var moved = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '#sub', function(){
        $('.circle').animate({
            'margin-left': (moved ? "-300" : 300 ) + "px"
        }, 500, 'swing', function() {
            moved = !moved;
            // or 
            moved = (moved ? 0 : 1);
        });
    });   
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That shorter version is quite nice. How does the '?' play a part in it?

Comment: it is called [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Okay great! then im guessing that function at the end is just doing a check?

Comment: Thats the callback function for when the animation is finished. Checkout [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the animate documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the browsers you need to support, it's probably better to hand of the animation to the css.
Simple toggle a class when clicking on the circle and use a css transition.

Something like this:
JS

```
$('.circle').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
}
```

CSS

```
.circle { transition: margin-left 0.2s; margin-left: -300px; }
.circle.clicked { margin-left: 3OOpx; }
```

Comment: yea, it would probrably be better to do that. Only reason in this case im using an if/else is to learn how it actually works and how it should be setup. Otherwise generally an add/remove or toggle class would be ideal!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting moved = 0 each time just before your if statement...

```
$(document).on('click', '#sub', function(){
  var moved = 0;  // <- This line here!
  if (moved == 0) {
     $('.circle').animate({'margin-left': "300px"});
     moved = 1;
  }
  else{
      moved = 0;
      $('.circle').animate({'margin-left': "-300px"});
  }
});
```

You'll need to move the declaration outside the function so it doesn't reset it each time.

Comment: fantastic. Didnt realize that by having that variable on the inside of the clicked it actually kept the value at 0. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Add class to the element when you first click and remove it on second click.

```
$(document).on('click', '#sub', function(){

if($('.circle').hasClass("clicked")){
   $('.circle').animate({'margin-left': "300px"});
   $('.circle').removeClass("clicked");
}else{
  $('.circle').animate({'margin-left': "-300px"});
  $('.circle').addClass("clicked");
}

});
```